# Merging a 2 dimentional json array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have two JSON arrays with multiple elements in each array. Could someone please help to merge these two arrays in order to add the second array elements with first array in respective to their index.

First JSON array:

```
$json1 =
    '[
    {
    "CHEPTEL":"12001116",
    "NOM":"La Ferme de Jean-Marc et Aurélien ",
    "CODE_POSTAL":"12630",
    "VILLE":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
    "LATITUDE":"44.343518",
    "LONGITUDE":"2.716004",
    "DESCRIPTIF_FERME":""     
    },
    {
    "CHEPTEL":"12001",
    "NOM":"La Ferme ",
    "CODE_POSTAL":"12630",
    "VILLE":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
    "LATITUDE":"44.343518",
    "LONGITUDE":"2.716004",
    "DESCRIPTIF_FERME":""
    }
    ]';
```

Second JSON array:

```
$json2= '[
    {
    "DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
    "ANNEE_ADHESION":"2016",
    "RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
    "DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
    },
    {
    "DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
    "ANNEE_ADHESION":"2016",
    "RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
    "DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
    }
    ]';
```

Finally I want to have the array to be this:

```
$newarray= '[
{
"CHEPTEL":"12001116",
"NOM":"La Ferme de Jean-Marc et Aurélien ",
"CODE_POSTAL":"12630",
"VILLE":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
"LATITUDE":"44.343518",
"LONGITUDE":"2.716004",
"DESCRIPTIF_FERME":"",  
"DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
"DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
"ANNEE_ADHESION":"2016",
"RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
"DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""    
},
{
"CHEPTEL":"12001",
"NOM":"La Ferme ",
"CODE_POSTAL":"12630",
"VILLE":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
"LATITUDE":"44.343518",
"LONGITUDE":"2.716004",
"DESCRIPTIF_FERME":"",
"DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
"ANNEE_ADHESION":"2016",
"RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
"DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
"DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
"ANNEE_ADHESION":"2016",
"RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
"DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
}
]';
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$finalArray = [];

foreach($json1 as $key => $obj){
    $newObj = array_merge($obj, $json2[$key]); 
    array_push($finalArray, $newObj);
}

you will get merged array in `$finalArray`
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `$newObj` is undefined; maybe `$newObj = array_merge($obj, $json2[$key]);`?

Comment: Opps..! @ArRakin answer edited.