# Remove Intial Nesting in JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

I have this JSON array starting with the nesting string "ELEVEURS" and I want to have it removed and should get the output as below. Could someone solve this please!

**INPUT**

```
 $json='{ "ELEVEURS" : 
       [{
        "CHEPTEL":"12001116",
        "NOM":"La Ferme de Jean-Marc et Aurélien ",
        "CODE_POSTAL":"12630                         ",
        "VILLE":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
        "LATITUDE":"44.343518",
        "LONGITUDE":"2.716004",
        "DESCRIPTIF_FERME":"",
        "DEMARCHE" : [
        {
        "DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
        "ANNEE_ADHESION":"2016",
        "RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
        "DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
        }
        ]
        },
        {
        "CHEPTEL":"12004022",
        "NOM":"La Ferme du Broussier ",
        "CODE_POSTAL":"12300                         ",
        "VILLE":"ALMONT LES JUNIES",
        "LATITUDE":"44.592071",
        "LONGITUDE":"2.328516",
        "DESCRIPTIF_FERME":"",
        "DEMARCHE" : [
        {
        "DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
        "ANNEE_ADHESION":"2000",
        "RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
        "DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
        }
        ]
        }'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$json='  [{
        "CHEPTEL":"12001116",
        "NOM":"La Ferme de Jean-Marc et Aurélien ",
        "CODE_POSTAL":"12630                         ",
        "VILLE":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
        "LATITUDE":"44.343518",
        "LONGITUDE":"2.716004",
        "DESCRIPTIF_FERME":"",
        "DEMARCHE" : [
        {
        "DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
        "ANNEE_ADHESION":"2016",
        "RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
        "DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
        }
        ]
        },
        {
        "CHEPTEL":"12004022",
        "NOM":"La Ferme du Broussier ",
        "CODE_POSTAL":"12300                         ",
        "VILLE":"ALMONT LES JUNIES",
        "LATITUDE":"44.592071",
        "LONGITUDE":"2.328516",
        "DESCRIPTIF_FERME":"",
        "DEMARCHE" : [
        {
        "DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
        "ANNEE_ADHESION":"2000",
        "RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
        "DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
        }
        ]'
```

I have this INPUT of JSON array starting with the nesting string "ELEVEURS" and I want to have it removed and should get the output as above. Could someone solve this please!

Comment: I think you're building something; would you like to tell us why you're using this JSON?

Comment: Please post the code you already have along with any errors you might get. This is not a coding service (as already stated in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951642/merging-a-2-dimentional-json-array-in-php))

Comment: @ArRakin Thanks Again. Sure, Its just that I am a beginner to PHP and I am very fond of PHP particularly. I took a sample data of arrays from a friend. Trying to create a system on my own to automate data from one FTP to Another without having to code it every time something is updated. And I should tell you, I feel like addicted to it.

Comment: @brombeer Hello, I am very new this platform and I have my own code with errors but thought It might not be useful, So I didn't post it. Its just that I didn't know how things work here. But thank you for letting me know. I will try to blend in with everyone.

Comment: @RanjitT As brombeer said, StackOverflow is not a coding service, so if you want then you can join my organization's forum at https://forums.onesoftnet.ml/ and post your problems there, I'll be happy to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error in your first JSON. I've corrected it in this answer.

```php
$json = '
{
     "ELEVEURS": [
          {
            "CHEPTEL":"12001116",
            "NOM":"La Ferme de Jean-Marc et Aurélien ",
            "CODE_POSTAL":"12630                         ",
            "VILLE":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
            "LATITUDE":"44.343518",
            "LONGITUDE":"2.716004",
            "DESCRIPTIF_FERME":"",
            "DEMARCHE" : [
                {
                "DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
                "ANNEE_ADHESION":"2016",
                "RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
                "DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
                }
            ]
          },
          {
                "CHEPTEL":"12004022",
                "NOM":"La Ferme du Broussier ",
                "CODE_POSTAL":"12300                         ",
                "VILLE":"ALMONT LES JUNIES",
                "LATITUDE":"44.592071",
                "LONGITUDE":"2.328516",
                "DESCRIPTIF_FERME":"",
                "DEMARCHE" : [
                    {
                        "DEMA_CODE":"08-93",
                        "ANNEE_ADHESION":"2000",
                        "RACE_MERES":"Limousine",
                        "DESCRIPTIF_ATELIER":""
                    }
                ]
            }
       ]
}';


echo(json_encode(json_decode($json)->ELEVEURS, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)); // done!
```